# Pandas - broadcasting daily data across intraday data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a frame of daily data and a frame of intraday data, and I'd like to add the two frames by broadcasting the daily data across each day. Minimal example below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

cols = ['A', 'B']
days = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=2, freq='D')
df_d = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(4).reshape((2, 2)), index=days, columns=cols)
hours = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=4, freq='12H')
df_h = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(8).reshape((4, 2)), index=hours, columns=cols)

target = pd.DataFrame([[0, 2],[2, 4],[6, 8],[8, 10]], index=hours, columns=cols)
```

```
>>> df_d                                                                                                                                                                                              
            A  B
2000-01-01  0  1
2000-01-02  2  3

>>> df_h                                                                                                                                                                                          
                     A  B
2000-01-01 00:00:00  0  1
2000-01-01 12:00:00  2  3
2000-01-02 00:00:00  4  5
2000-01-02 12:00:00  6  7

>>> target                                                                                                                                                                                            
                     A   B
2000-01-01 00:00:00  0   2
2000-01-01 12:00:00  2   4
2000-01-02 00:00:00  6   8
2000-01-02 12:00:00  8  10
```

So I would want to do `target = df_h "+" df_d` in a robust way as the intraday timestamps could change and there could be NaNs in the data. I tried reindexing `df_d` to `hours` and then forward filling, but this doesn't inherently respect daily boundaries and is fragile to missing data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.add`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add.html) after normalizing the index of `df_h`:

```
i = df_h.index
df_h.set_index(i.floor('D')).add(df_d, fill_value=0).set_index(i)
```

---

```
                     A   B
2000-01-01 00:00:00  0   2
2000-01-01 12:00:00  2   4
2000-01-02 00:00:00  6   8
2000-01-02 12:00:00  8  10
```